# How do I detect a fatal error when fstream data is being written to disk?

Tags: c++, error-handling, fstream

What's the right way to check that no fatal errors have occurred after flushing data from a C++ fstream object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a derivative of ios, fstream provides a means to check for errors on i/o operations. You can [rdstate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdstate/) or you can check [good](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/) on the stream to look for errors.